# deploy wordpress database settings and not content

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment, web-deployment

What is the best way to deploy wordpress database settings to production without having to migrate the entire database? I am using git and https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli. If I have a development branch checkout out need to merge this back in to master, there must be a way to deploy database settings without having to migrate the full database including content. In Drupal there is a module called 'Features' which handles this process. Any suggestions regarding wordpress deployment processes across multiple development environments would be fantastic.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean with database settings.

All information needed to access the database is held in `wp-config.php`

If you want to copy the database structure, that would be a MySQL dump.

Comment: I'll try and explain. My next release requires 4 new modules. I install these modules locally, then configure each module via each modules settings section. These settings are stored in the database. I then put the production site into maintenance mode for deployment. If I migrate the entire local database to production, this will also migrate an older snapshot of site content. How do others manage this? Is the best method to manually update module settings on production?

Comment: @peter are you saying you can define module database settings via wp-config.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define "module", WordPress term is plugin, in `wp-config.php` The plugin settings are stored in the table _options table, but some plugins use multiple rows, others create entire new tables.

If the plugin doesn't have the option to export/import the settings, you can almost forget about it. You would have to dig in the code to figure out the names of the rows in the DB and if the the plugin creates new tables.

Comment: Thanks for the insights @peter. How to the big guns of wordpress manage their deployments? There must be a good work around?

Comment: What about exporting site content after putting production in to maintenance mode to get a snapshot of all content, refresh the productions database from local, then import all content in to production again?

Comment: There's one catch with exporting, your site url, admin info (name, pwd, email), site name, all are exported as well. To make it work on a different URL, you need to replace all this info before importing it on the new site. I do this(the URL and admin email) for developing and testing my site locally. I could put it in a gist on Github if you want to see it.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That would be great. What I am struggling to find though is a definitive git deployment plan for wordpress sites. Maybe my googling is not up to par, but this would be a common consideration no?